# Find CHAR(219) and CHAR(220) then change its font to Wingding 3

Tags: excel, vba

I am new at Excel macro.

My question is how to create a macro to find CHAR(219) and CHAR(220) in the sheet, then change its font to Wingding 3.

I don't need to change font color or size etc.

```vb
Sub SpecialChar()
    Dim strPatt As String
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim regEx As Object
 
    strPatt = "[ÜÛ]" 'change pattern as needed
 
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
 
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = strPatt
    End With
 
    For Each cel In Range("A:ZZ").End(xlUp).Row).Cells 'change column as needed
        If regEx.Test(cel.Text) Then
            cel.font.Name = "Wingding 3"
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: May I suggest that you use Conditional Formatting with Icon Sets to achieve this, instead of a VB macro?

Comment: @tinazmu thank you for asking, however, boss want me to create macro button. I already suggest conditional formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font is 'Wingdings 3', not 'Wingding 3'; this should work:

```
Public Sub ChangeThem()
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If cel = Chr(219) Or cel = Chr(220) Then
           cel.Font.Name = "Wingdings 3"
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```